# How to implement editable text in Meteor and DRY?

Tags: meteor, dry

I have come up with a methodology for making editable text in my Meteor app. However, it does not follow the DRY paradigm and I'd like to change that but I am not too good with Javascript yet...

Suppose I have a table cell with some text and I'd like to double click it to edit it. I created a template variable to handle this:

```
<td class="itemName">
    {{#unless editItemName}}
        {{name}} 
    {{else}}
        <input class="editItemName" type="text" value="{{name}}" style="width:100px;">
    {{/unless}}
</td>
```

I then create an event to execute this transition on a double-click:

```
Template.inventoryItemDetail.events = {

'dblclick td.itemName': function (evt) {
  Session.set("editItemName",true);
},
'blur input.editItemName': function () {
  Session.set("editItemName",null);
},};
```

I also reused the ok_cancel code from the ToDo's example app (but that's sort of irrelevant):

```
  // Returns an event_map key for attaching "ok/cancel" events to
  // a text input (given by selector)
  var okcancel_events = function (selector) {
    return 'keyup '+selector+', keydown '+selector+', focusout '+selector;
  };

  // Creates an event handler for interpreting "escape", "return", and "blur"
  // on a text field and calling "ok" or "cancel" callbacks.
  var make_okcancel_handler = function (options) {
    var ok = options.ok || function () {};
    var cancel = options.cancel || function () {};

    return function (evt) {
      if (evt.type === "keydown" && evt.which === 27) {
        // escape = cancel
        cancel.call(this, evt);
        evt.currentTarget.blur();


      } else if (evt.type === "keyup" && evt.which === 13) {
        // blur/return/enter = ok/submit if non-empty
        var value = String(evt.target.value || "");
        if (value) {
          ok.call(this, value, evt);
          evt.currentTarget.blur();
        }
        else {
          cancel.call(this, evt);
          evt.currentTarget.blur();
        }
      }
    };
  };

Template.inventoryItemDetail.events[ okcancel_events('input.editItemName') ] = make_okcancel_handler({
ok: function (value) {
  Items.update(this._id, {$set: {name: value}});
}
});
```

Finally, I have to tie this Session variable to the template variable:

```
Template.inventoryItemDetail.editItemName = function () {
  return Session.get("editItemName");
};
```

So right now, I have repeated all of this again and again for each editable text field and it all works, but it seems like terribly programming practice. I have found various editable text utilities on Github but I don't entirely understand them and none of them are for Meteor!

I'd really like to expand my knowledge of Meteor and Javascript by creating a tool that allows me to have editable text without repeating myself this ridiculous amount for each editable text field.

Thanks,

Chet

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/nate-strauser/meteor-x-editable-bootstrap for the package.

http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html for the docs.

I just implemented this in my project and I won't ever go back to `contenteditable`.

Comment: I saw this when I was looking around. I don't quite understand it. 

1) what is `contenteditable`?

2) how would I use this package for what I am doing -- editing database attributes, etc.?